# xamarin ios set installed keyboard as inputview

Tags: ios, xamarin, keyboard

I am trying to set an installed keyboard as the default input for a UITextField. Imagine you have a custom emoji keyboard called "AwesomeEmojis" and you want that keyboard to be the default keyboard programmatically . I have this code:

```
NSObject[] installedKeyboards = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.ArrayForKey("AppleKeyboards");
```

I am able to see the list of keyboard in a NSMutableString format like:

```
"awesomeemoji@sw=AwesomeEmoji"
```

Is there any way that i can do something like:

```
AwesomeTextField.InputView = FromSystemKeyboards["awesomeemoji@sw=AwesomeEmoji"];
```

Please keep in mind the it's not a system keyboard. It's installed keyboard.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it your keyboard extension and are you trying to assign it to an `InputView` within its container app?

Comment: Hi Sushi. I do not fully understand your question but, let's say you have an installed keyboard. You are able to see it on your iPhone's settings and enabling it. If that keyboard exists, and it's enabled i want to be the default keyboard for a specific UITextField. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: My question is it *your* Keyboard extension (not a 3rd party keyboard) and are your trying to use it within your own container app? Otherwise, I know of no way to assign a 3rd-party keyboard within your own app, that is strictly a iOS function via switching via the globe key to allow the end-user to switch installed 3rd-party keyboards at will...

Comment: Yes, it's a 3rd party keyboard. I guess you answered my question then: "...I know of no way to assign a 3rd-party keyboard within your own app, that is strictly a iOS function via switching via the globe key to allow the end-user to switch installed 3rd-party keyboards at will..."